# How to push item name from Zoho Books to Zoho Creator using Custom function?

Tags: zoho, zohobooks, zoho-deluge

There are multiple module in Zoho Books,
Suppose I need to push data of Estimate into Zoho Creator, I have created similar form in Zoho Creator as well as I made a connection with Zoho Books to Zoho Creator.
I am able to push other data except this **Item & Description**.
How can I push these data into Zoho Creator?
[image: I have added an image of items, I need to push these names]

Answer (score 0):

```
resp = zoho.books.getRecordsByID("Estimate",rec_ID);
lines_items_resp = resp.get("estimate").getJSON("line_items");
for each rec in lines_items_resp {
    info rec.getJSON("id"); //line items id
}
```

Comment: How I can map item data field ?

Comment: for each rec in lines_items_resp 
 {
  items_id= rec.getJSON("id");//line items id
  check_rec_existance=FORM_NAME[CRITERIA];
  if(check_rec_existance.count()==0)
  {
   //insert records
   new_item = insert into FORM_NAME_SUBFORM
   [
    Added_User = zoho.loginuser
    book_line_items_id = items_id.tolong()
    name=rec.getJSON("...")
   ];
  }
  else 
        {
   //update records
   check_rec_existance.name=rec.getJSON("...");
        }
 }